# Celery: How to detect the count of active task handlers from the MainProcess?

Tags: python, celery

I seems there's a bug in Celery where warm shutdown in prefork pool (MainProcess + Fork task handler processes) is not gracefully terminating because by the time the task is done the connection to the broker was closed already.

Late ack doesn't fix that.

To fix it by myself I thought to manage the count of the running tasks so that when there are tasks running then to postpone the call to Celery's SIGTERM handler up to the moment there are no running tasks then let the call pass and shutting down.

**The problem I'm facing is how can I detect in the MainProcess the count of the running tasks in child forked processes?**

task_prerun and task_postrun [signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) are handled in child forked processes so they aren't very useful to the logic in the MainProcess.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the logic... When Worker gets the graceful shutdown (either via the SIGTERM, but also it could be sent to the worker using celery control API) it unsubsribes from all queues and waits for the running worker processes to finish, before it shuts down.

Comment: Celery has the boolean feature of "late_ack" that allows the task to be acknowledged when it's done. However, a long task cannot be "acked" because the connection with the broker is closed after a while since heartbeat keepalives are stopped being sent.
If the authors of Celery were thinking right they should have stopped the consumer from accepting any more tasks and when the active tasks with late_ack finish *then* close the connection.
The open bug is in here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3802

Comment: I know about the [task_acks_late](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-late) - I use it by default (it is always true in my configurations). That bug is a regression that got fixed.